# Implementing Childbrowser in Sencha Touch using Phone Gap

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, extjs

I am currently deploying for Android OS in Sencha Touch 2.

I have included the path  for "cordova-2.2.0.js" ,"ChildBrowser.js" in the app.json file

I am developing it in Windows PC with Chrome browser and deploying using Sencha tool and phonegap build to android device.

My sample code is

**window.plugins.childBrowser.openExternal("http://www.google.com");**

I get following error in my webkit browser.

Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'exec'

And in my native app I am not getting any response.

Please Help ...i am Including my Main.js file

**Thank you**

Main.js file

```
Ext.define('Children.view.Main', {
extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
xtype: 'main',
requires: [
    'Ext.TitleBar',
    'Ext.Video'
],
config: {
    tabBarPosition: 'bottom',

    items: [
        {
            title: 'Welcome',
            iconCls: 'home',

            styleHtmlContent: true,

            items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'button',
                            text: 'Open Google',
                            handler: function(button) {

                                         window.plugins.childBrowser.openExternal('http://www.google.com');
                            }
                        }

                    ]
        },
        {
            title: 'Get Started',
            iconCls: 'action',

            items: [
                {
                    docked: 'top',
                    xtype: 'titlebar',
                    title: 'Getting Started'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'video',
                    url: 'http://av.vimeo.com/64284/137/87347327.mp4?token=1330978144_f9b698fea38cd408d52a2393240c896c',
                    posterUrl: 'http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/261/062/261062119_640.jpg'
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

This is simply a very big big big question:
To do that you need several technical skills: javascript, sencha touch, java (for Android OS) and phonegap plugin
Are you able to write a phonegap plugin?
A short receipt to do that but I do not include the Java code, because I need more details from you:

- in config.xml under res/xml put your plugin config (InfoP is a Java class):
- add InfoPlugin.java in your src folder;
- add infopl.js under assets/www; (infopl.js is the javascript wich call the Java plugin)
- in index.html (for example) the plugin:

In the webapp you can call the plugin:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {

      window.plugins.infoPl.getInfo(
           function(info) {

                alert(info);
           //( you can see what you log on console with ADB console log)
                console.log('MYINFO: '+info); 
           }, function() {
               console.log("fail");
           }
       );

  }, false );
</script>
```

In Sencha use (better if you use a controller with MVC capabilities of sencha touch):

```
  listeners: {
    tap:
     function() {
        alert('something');
    }
```

instead of:

```
handler: function(button) {
  alert('something');

}
```

You suggest you to check:

- http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.6.0/guide_plugin-development_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide
- http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.0/#!/video/mvc-part-1